# How to use ISNULL() function along with join

Tags: sql

While using the ISNULL function along with aliases of column name that I have given to form a left join, I get an error.

The error is:
[image]

I am unable to understand what am I doing wrong. The data is stored in customers table:
[image]

The sql code that I am using is:

```
select ISNULL(c2.name,'N/A') as referredby , c1.name as name
from customers as c1
    left outer join customers as c2 on c1.referredby = c2.id
order by referredby;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (ISNULL is a product specific function.)

Comment: Try `COALESCE(c2.name,'N/A')` instead of `ISNULL`

Comment: Seems like you're using DB2 where ISNULL does not exist. Use coalesce().

Comment: coalesce works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `isnull()`!  The standard version is `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(cref.name, 'N/A') as referredby_name, c.name as name
from customers c left outer join
     customers cref
     on c.referredby = cref.id
order by referredby_name;
```

I made a two other changes.  First, the table aliases better describe the role of the tables.  I also changed the column alias to `referredby_name`, so it doesn't match a column in a table.  Neither of these are required; with them, I think the query reads more easily.